# why is `std::initializer_list` often passed by value?

Tags: c++, c++11

In almost every post I see on SO, involving a `std::initializer_list`, people tend to pass a `std::initializer_list` by value. According to this article:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120707045924/cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

one should pass by value, if one wants to make a copy of the passed object. But copying a `std::initializer_list` is not a good idea, as

> Copying a `std::initializer_list` does not copy the underlying objects.
> The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of
> the original initializer list object has ended.

So why is an instance of it often passed by value and not by, say `const&`, which guaranteed does not make a needless copy?

Comment: As I understand it, compilers identify the common 'return by value' idiom and optimise it as a "move" instead, which doesn't actually involve any memory copy in its implementation.

Comment: @MatthewD We’re not talking about returning here though.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It’s passed by value because it’s cheap. `std::initializer_list`, being a thin wrapper, is most likely implemented as a pair of pointers, so copying is (almost) as cheap as passing by reference. In addition, we’re not actually performing a copy, we’re (usually) performing a *move* since in most cases the argument is constructed from a temporary anyway. However, this won’t make a difference for performance – moving two pointers is as expensive as copying them.

On the other hand, *accessing* the elements of a copy may be *faster* since we avoid one additional dereferencing (that of the reference).

Comment: `const&` is not necessarily implemented as a pointer though (if I remember the standard correctly), it could be some kind of an alias as well.

Comment: @user1095108 True, the standard doesn’t specify that. However, in the real world there isn’t a magical “alias” type. A reference is either elided completely – in local scope we can just refer to the original entity instead – or replaced by a pointer. If you pass a value by reference *to a function* (and that function isn’t inlined), it’s practically *guaranteed* to be replaced by a pointer.

Comment: + accessing the elements is usually done with iterators. Once these are obtained, one does not need to dereference the passed `const&` anymore.

Comment: @user1095108 True as well. However, the mere cost of accessing them *once* via a reference may well offset the cost of copying one additional pointer when passing the argument (in fact, it probably comes out the same).

Comment: If I may surmise. The pass by value idea rests on the assumption that copying a `std::initializer_list` is cheap, but this is guaranteed nowhere. Pass by `const &` may not be a bad idea after all.

Comment: @user1095108 It’s actually kind-of guaranteed: the standard *also* passes `std::initializer_list` by value. That’s a very strong hint. If the standard library uses pass-by-value then you’re safe doing the same thing because even if it were inefficient you’d suffer that effect anyway. Furthermore, the standard gives explicit advice of how to implement it (§18.9/2: “A pair of pointers or a pointer plus a length would be obvious representations for `initializer_list`.”).

Comment: @user1095108 Conceptually, an `initializer_list` is two iterators.  The entire STL is designed around the assumption that copying iterators is cheap.  There are a lot more arguments in favor of pass by value than those that Konrad presents---the most important is probably that the passed value will be a temporary with a trivial destructor, and so can be constructed directly as the argument is probably the most telling---but considerations of performance cannot be invoked against pass by value.

Answer (score 17):

Probably for the same reasons iterators are almost always passed by value: copying an iterator is considered "cheap".  In the case of `initializer_list`, there's also the fact that most instances will be temporaries with trivial destructors, so the compiler can construct them directly where it puts the function argument, with no copy.  Finally, there's the fact that, like iterators, the called function is likely to want to modify the value, which means that it would have to copy it locally if it were passed by a reference to const.

EDIT:

Just to generalize: the standard library makes the assumption in general that it is better to pass iterators, initializer_lists, and functional objects by value.  As a result, you should ensure that any iterators, iterator_lists or functional objects you design are cheap to copy, and you should assume in your own code that they are cheap to copy.  The traditional rule about when to use references to const, and when to use value, should probably be modified to reflect this:

> Use pass by reference to const for class types other than iterators, initializer_lists or functional objects; use pass by value otherwise.

Comment: But why copy, say, a `std::function<>` instance? Surely it is not cheap to copy.

Comment: @user1095108 The standard library passes it by copy, always.  So an implementation should do whatever it takes for it to be cheap to copy.  (And you should avoid doing things which would make it expensive to copy: an `std::function` with a large `std::vector` inside it is _not_ a good idea.)

Comment: Speaking of `std::function`: The result of `std::bind` can be moved from one another, and moving will move bound arguments. I debugged to verify that this is the case. Therefore, it should be relatively efficient to move from `std::function`'s that contain, for example, bound vectors - since vectors can be efficiently moved from.

Comment: @haelix Move semantics introduce another set of issues to consider, but I don't think they change the general rule much.  Initialization lists are probably always used in contexts where  move is relevant; iterators often not.  Functional objects vary, depending on the type of object.  I'd still try and make all three cheap to copy; supporting move depends on just how cheap I succeed in making copy.

Comment: @user1095108 Even if we accepted that some `std::function`s were not cheap to copy, other kinds of functor are usually pretty much free.

Comment: by `iterator_lists` I think you mean `initializer_lists`