# How call a constructor with std::initializer_list of a user type in ChaiScript?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, chaiscript, stdinitializerlist

I have the next definition class:

```
class MyType {
public:
    MyType();
    MyType(int x);
    MyType(std::initializer_list<MyType> list);
}
```

I register my custom class and its constructors in ChaiScript v6.0.0 as follows:

```
chai.add(chaiscript::user_type<MyType>(), "MyType");
chai.add(chaiscript::constructor<MyType()>(), "MyType");
chai.add(chaiscript::constructor<MyType(int)>(), "MyType");
chai.add(chaiscript::constructor<MyType(std::initializer_list<MyType>)>(), "MyType");
```

I have the next scripts:

```
std::string script1 = R""(
    def Test1() {
        var m = MyType();
    }

    Test1();
)"";
auto res = chai.eval<MyType>(script1);


std::string script2 = R""(
    def Test2() {
        var m = MyType(10);
    }

    Test2();
)"";
auto res2 = chai.eval<MyType>(script2);


std::string script3 = R""(
    def Test3() {
        var m = MyType({10, 20});
    }

    Test3();
)"";
auto res3 = chai.eval<MyType>(script3);
```

`script1` and `script2` run without problems, but `script3` give me the next execution error:

```
Error: "Incomplete equation" during evaluation  at (9, 14)
```

What is the correct way to call the constructor `MyType(std::initializer_list<MyType>)` from ChaiScript?

Comment: Note: A proper `std::initializer_list<>` constructor would look like this: `MyType(std::initializer_list<MyType> list);` See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17803511/2296177

Comment: @user2296177 Thanks for the format suggestion.

Comment: @chema989: Does ChaiScript have a way to register a variadic function? If it doesn't, I can't see a way for ChaiScript to be able to do this. All `initializer_list` instances ultimately come from a braced-init-list. Which is a C++ syntactic construct; ChaiScript cannot manufacture such a thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas ChaiScript doesn't have a way to register a variadic function, It is necessary register a function for each possible combination of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChaiScript doesn't have a way to register a variadic function, it is necessary register a function for each possible combination of arguments and cannot manufacture braced-init-list like C++.

The workaround that I found was to add a constructor for `MyType` that receive a vector:

```
class MyType {
public:
    MyType();
    MyType(int x);
    MyType(std::initializer_list<MyType> list);
    MyType(const std::vector<MyType>& v);
}
```

Register my custom class and its constructors in ChaiScript v6.0.0 as follows:

```
chai.add(chaiscript::user_type<MyType>(), "MyType");
chai.add(chaiscript::constructor<MyType()>(), "MyType");
chai.add(chaiscript::constructor<MyType(int)>(), "MyType");
chai.add(chaiscript::constructor<MyType(const std::vector<MyType>&)>(), "MyType");
```

And change `script3` for:

```
std::string script3 = R""(
    def Test3() {
        var m = MyType([MyType(10), MyType(20)]);
    }

    Test3();
)"";
```