# Efficient way of providing an initializer list constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, initializer-list, perfect-forwarding

Let's say, a class `Base` with following resorces:

```
struct Base
{
    int m_int;
    bool m_flag;
    float m_float;
    Base() = delete; // just to see that it didn't call
    Base(int a, bool b, float c): m_int(a), m_flag(b), m_float(c) {}

};
```

Then I have a `SubClass` which has a vector of `Base` class as the resource.

- After researching I found that using perfect forwarding or forwarding
  reference, `Base`  class resources can be created much efficiently as it avoids the unnecessary call of default constructors(please correct
  me, if I am wrong).
- In addition to the forwarding technique, I wanted also to have an
  initializer list constructor, so that I can have an aggregate
  inilitation possible for `SubClass`

Then I came up with following code for my `SubClass`.

```
struct SubClass
{
private:
    std::vector<Base> vec;
public:
    SubClass() = delete; // just to see that it didn't call

    // Idea - 1
    //SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base>&& all): vec(std::move(all)) {}

    // Idea - 2
    SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base> all): vec(all) {}

    // Idea - 3 : but no more list initialization possible
    template<typename ...Arg>
    void addToClass(Arg&& ...args)
    {
        vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Arg>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Then in the `main()`, I can have following two possibilities to update resources in `SubClass`:

```
int main()
{
    // possibility - 1
    SubClass obj
    {
       {1, true, 2.0f },
       {5, false, 7.0f},
       {7, false, 9.0f},
       {8, true, 0.0f},
    };
    //possibility - 2: without list initialization
    /*obj.addToClass(1, true, 2.0f);
    obj.addToClass(5, false, 7.0f);
    obj.addToClass(7, false, 9.0f);
    obj.addToClass(8, true, 0.0f);*/

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Question - 1:**

Which one of following is efficient or good to use(good practice) in above case? Why?

```
// Idea - 1
SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base>&& all): vec(std::move(all)) {}

// Idea - 2
SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base> all): vec(all) {}
```

**Question - 2:**

Does `addToClass(Arg&& ...args)` function works similar to any of the above two ideas?

Comment: Question 1 is basically answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803475/why-is-stdinitializer-list-often-passed-by-value

Comment: @NathanOliver I have read that. Thats why I made `SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base> all): vec(all) {}`. However, is it the only best way we should follow? My doubt is mainly, whether **idea - 1** may act like *perfect forwarding*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first.

```
SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base>&& all): vec(std::move(all)) {}
```

and

```
SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base> all): vec(all) {}
```

Don't do the same thing.  The first also needs

```
SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base>& all): vec(all) {}
```

So you can initialize it with an lvalue `std::initializer_list` (may never happen but it could).  Passing by value covers both of those overloads so it is easier to write and it's performance is just about as good (it would take a lot of operations to really make a difference)

You can't move objects out of a `std::initializer_list` since the objects as marked as `const` so

```
SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base>&& all): vec(std::move(all)) {}
```

doesn't actually move anything.

As for `addToClass` you can have both.  You can have your template version that emaplces a single object into the class.  You can also add an overload to take a `std::initializer_list` so you can add multiple objects like

```
void addToClass(std::initializer_list<Base> all)
{
    vec.insert(vec.end(), all.begin(), all.end());
}
```

and that will add all of the objects in `all` to the end of `vec`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  So from your answer, **idea - 1** will work like pass by ref. (`SubClass(std::initializer_list<Base>& all): vec(all) {}`), right? If so this is bad as per the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803475/why-is-stdinitializer-list-often-passed-by-value) I have.

Comment: @Malayalam With idea one you pass the list by rvalue reference.  That stops you from begin able to pass an lvalue list which means you have to add another overload which means more chances of messing something up.  If you just pass by value you basically get the same performance and less typing/error sources.  In basically all cases I see list being passed by value.

Comment: Okay. I got it now. Thanks for explaining to me.