# why am i getting a "no instance of constructor matches the MyArray::MyArray" argument list?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class MyArray {
    int* array;
public:
    MyArray(){}
    MyArray(std::initializer_list<int>& v) {
        array = new int[v.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for (auto element : v) {
            array[index] = element;
            index++;
        }
    }

    ~MyArray()
    {
        delete[] array;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyArray object{ 2,4,2,2 };
}
```

This is my first time working with std::initializer for object list initialization. I have created a an array that is initialized using the MyArray constructor. i don't know where am i going wrong. i created an object that matches the argument list, ie a constructor that takes an initializer list.

Answer (score 3):

> i created an object that matches the argument list, ie a constructor that takes an initializer list.

You didn't; not quite.

You created a constructor that takes a *reference* to an `std::initializer_list`.

But one created in this manner is [possibly] a temporary that cannot bind to such a reference.

Generally you just want to take `std::initializer_list`s by value. That is: **remove the `&`.**

There are some examples on [cppreference's article on `std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: i have hard time understanding the contents on cppreference, my IQ went downhill after i started learning c++. thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: It's okay, your IQ is safe: just the confusion level will go up with anything relating to this ghastly language :P

Comment: Can you also use `const` reference, to extend the life of the temporary object?

Comment: @ChrisMM I guess so, but that doesn't really gain you anything over just taking a value, and is not idiomatic (probably because it doesn't really gain you anything). Have a read of _"[why is `std::initializer_list` often passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17803475/560648)"_.

Answer (score 0):

`MyArray object{ 2,4,2,2 };`

Actually this is invoking move assignment of MyArray.
{ 2,4,2,2 } is a rvalue and you can't bind it to a reference.

You need to understand what is rvalue reference and move semantics, and here is a good answer:
[What is move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)