# Initializing some elements of vector of defined size

Tags: c++, vector

Is there a way to initialize first few elements of a vector after defining the size of the vector like -

```
vector<int> vec (10);
```

This doesn't work and produces a compiler error -

```
vector<int> vec(10) {1,2,3};
```

For example with arrays we can do the same thing like -

```
int arr[5] {1,2,3}; // This will initialize the first 3 elements of the array to 1,2,3 and the remaining two to 0.
```

Answer (score 5):

In short, no. Your can fill out the entire list of things you want to be in the vector:

```
vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Which will give you a `vector` of 10 elements.

Or, you can create the `vector`, then call `resize` to make it larger (filling the remaining elements with `0`):

```
vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
vec.resize(10);
```

You generally don't need to do this kind of thing to `vector` though, because unlike `array`, you can extend vector as needed, *after* creation:

```
vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
vec.push_back(4);
```

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a way to do it all in one line like you can with an array.  You can use

```
vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
vec.resize(10);
```

but that does make the code a little less easy to use.  Another option is to wrap that in a function like

```
template <typename T> 
auto make_sized_vector(std::intializer_list<T> il, std::size_t size = 0)
{
    const auto vec_size = std::max(size, il.size());
    vector<T> vec;            // create vector
    vec.reserve(vec_size);    // allocate all the storage needed
    vec.assign(il);           // assign the elements
    vec.resize(vec_size);     // set the rest to zero
    return vec;
}
```

and then you can use that like

```
auto vec = make_sized_vector<int>({1, 2, 3}, 10);
```

---

If you are concerned about passing the `std::intializer_list` by value see [why is `std::initializer_list` often passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803475/why-is-stdinitializer-list-often-passed-by-value) for why that really isn't a concern.

Comment: Given the second solution is not more efficient (same resize(), which might implicate a realloc)... the first one is both readable and honest as to its performance trade-offs. Of course, you could improve upon the implementation of the second version to avoid the resize, using a UH OH DEAR ME OH DEAR for loop. :)

Comment: @BitTickler `resize` here wont cause an allocation since the new size is not greater then the capacity.

Comment: Oh right! Yes, agreed, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to *initialize* a vector the way you describe, all at once, so that it can become (e.g.) a `const` member, this is always possible in C++, with just a bit of ugliness and twisting. Let’s say you have a class:

```cpp
struct SomeClass {
  SomeClass(const std::vector<int> &start, int rest, std::size_t size);
  const std::vector<int> some_vector_;  // This is const!
};
```

What the constructor could look like:

```cpp
SomeClass::SomeClass(const std::vector<int> &start, int rest, std::size_t size)
    : some_vector_{[&start, rest, size] {
        std::vector<int> some_vector;
        some_vector.reserve(size);
        some_vector.insert(some_vector.end(), start.begin(), start.end());
        some_vector.insert(some_vector.end(), size - start.size(), rest);
        return some_vector;
      }()} {}
```

Basically the problem boils down to: *How do I do “something procedural” in an initializer list?* To which the answer is: *You invoke a function that returns the desired type.*

To test the construct above:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace { /* SomeClass stuff from above goes here. */ }

int main() {
  SomeClass sc{{1, 2, 3}, 0, 10};
  for (int i : sc.some_vector_) std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

There are (of course) plenty of ways to make it (slightly) more efficient if needed, such as

- a templated variadic constructor to create the initial part of the vector,
- a templated perfect-forwarding constructor to benefit from R-value containers, and
- as a combined benefit of the above, arbitrary iterable containers as inputs and as the `const` member.